# Background tasks

Tags: ios, background, push-notification

I know there is a way to have an application that has been sent to a background session either execute a finite length task or to have long running tasks if they are of specific types ([apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)).

My question is, is it possible to have an iOS application task run even if the application has been closed and send an internal push notification when some event takes place similar to android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use push notifications for that. Even if the app is closed, your app can respond to a push notification and start a new task. I'd start your research here:

[Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57)
[Tracking the User's Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25)
[Starting the Significant-Change Location Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8)

Comment: But can the closed application do something like wait for a specific location of the user to come up and then send the push notification?

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible. I know the Dropbox app responds to location changes to let big file uploads/downloads continue so their background tasks don't get shut down after 5 minutes. [Tracking the User's Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25)

Comment: Does that happen even if the application has been closed manually by the user?

Comment: Yes as long as they give you permission to track their location even when the app is closed it should still work when they force close. There is a permission for that.

Comment: I have given it permission in the plist file. The application continues to update location when suspended, however, when it is closed then application seems to stop. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see the significant-change location link I've added to my answer. It should help you. Detecting a significant change in location should allow you to start up a terminated app to run a background task.

Comment: I set up a local notification in the location update delegate method but when the application has been closed it does not update. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you request permission to access their location? Maybe are running into [this issue](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)

Comment: Yes. All general location services are running fine and my required background mode is set to "App registers for location updates". I am finding a lot of documentation that leads me to believe once an application is terminate it can no longer run anything.

Comment: "If you leave the significant-change location service running and your iOS app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives. At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location services and process the location data." You should be able to start the task back up again. Just make sure the service is running when they'd be force closing and you start the service again when your app wakes up.